# How to reset style to unique render Leaflet js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, gis, arcgis-js-api

I have a layer in my map that the user can change the style of. I also have the ability to highlight layers on `mouseover`. The problem is that if a user chooses to change the style of a layer after initialization of the map, I can no longer use the built in `resetStyle` method because it will revert the entire layer to its initial style and not the unique rendering that the user chose. Now I am using `setFeatureStyle` on any layer with unique rendering to run it through a function that recreates the desired style based on a feature attribute, however now on `mouseout` those features are raising to the top of the map, above features they were originally placed underneath ruining the consistency in the map.

```
$scope.resetHighlight = function(e) {
        var layer = e.layer
        if(!e.target.tblField){ //This checks if there is unique rendering
            e.target.resetStyle(layer.id)
        }
        else{
            layer = e.layer;
            e.target.setFeatureStyle(layer.feature.id, uniqueStyle)
        }
    }
```

The code above is triggered on `mouseout` if it just uses the resetStyle method the layers' z-values are uneffected, however if I use the `setFeatureStyle` and run it through the function that bases styling on feature attributes the feature then rises to the top(highest z-value).

- Is there a method for reverting back to a style that was set after
  initialization?
- Where on the leaflet layer object or feature object can I find the
  layers current style and not its original style on page load?
- How do I prevent the layer from changing its z-value when using the
  `setFeatureStyle` method?

Comment: Are you sure that the features are being brought to the front on `mouseout` and not earlier than that? Does your `mouseover` listener code use `.bringToFront()`? I don't think Leaflet's styling functions change the rendering order on their own, and a quick look at esri-leaflet's `setFeatureStyle` code (I assume you are using esri-leaflet here?) doesn't seem to indicate that it does either.

Comment: Well I think when you setFeatureStyle it redraws the features and the layering is based on the order in which the features are drawn. Super surprised they didn't include a simple layer manager in the featureLayer object to insure things are drawn correctly.